# Unable to add SQL Server DataSource in JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, sql-server, jboss

I am trying to add an SQL Server datasource in JBoss EAP 7.2 through the management console. However, the Test Connection operation is failing. Below are the version details:

JBoss EAP - 7.2

MSSQL Driver Jar - mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar

**Module.xml:**

```
<module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**Module Directory Structure:** 
jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main

**Standalone.xml Datasource and Driver Configuration:**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/MSSQLDS" pool-name="MSSQLDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.XX.XX;DatabaseName=MYTESTDB1</connection-url>
    <datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>mydb_xxxx</user-name>
        <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
    </security>
</datasource>

<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

**Server Logs:**

```
13:21:52,267 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ020020: Connection Properties for DataSource: 'java:/MSSQLDS' is empty, try to use driver-class: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' and connection-url: 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.XX.XX;DatabaseName=MYTESTDB1' to connect database
13:21:52,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:21:52,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MSSQLDS]
13:21:52,640 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
13:21:52,803 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final-redhat-00001 (Apache CXF 3.2.5.redhat-00001)
13:21:54,308 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Estrella Galicia' 9.3.3.Final-redhat-00001
13:21:54,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
13:21:54,792 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:21:54,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:21:54,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 8695ms - Started 477 of 663 services (333 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
13:22:21,345 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1067)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:240)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:97)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1411)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:265)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:231)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:212)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:246)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:257)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2385)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:567)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1955)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:719)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:79)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:314)
        ... 35 more

13:22:21,350 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MSSQLDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

Update - 
Even though i have specified the IP address of my database, JBoss is trying to connect to localhost instead of that IP. 
I have verified and ruled out any network / firewall related problems. Through a sample Java/SpringBoot project, i am able to open a JDBC connection to the database. However, the datasource creation from JBoss is failing.

Comment: Log says: "The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed." check your TCP connection and the relative port.

Comment: Hi Max, I reckon that's the problem that even though i have specified IP address for my database, JBoss is trying to connect to localhost. I notice a statement in the logs saying - IJ020020: Connection Properties for DataSource: 'java:/MSSQLDS' is empty, try to use driver-class: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'

Not sure why it says Connection Properties empty even though all the fields like DB URL, driver class, datasource class are provided

Comment: I think the Jboss don't read your xml, [docs says](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration) to place the config on Datasource Definitions under `subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0"`

Comment: Make sure that TCP/IP is enabled in MSSql Server. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388042/connect-to-sql-server-2008-with-tcp-ip question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I am able to connect to the database directly through a Java program, however, its the JBoss datasource creation which is failing. Another thing i notice, is that even though i have the connection-url and driver details specified, JBoss reports that connection properties are empty. I reckon this is the main problem, just that i am yet to figure the solution out.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution finally. It’s a problem with Wildfly when the **datasource-class** is used while adding the driver module.

With the datasource class, explicit connection properties are required and the connection-url tag is “effectively” ignored. By “effectively” ignored, I mean JBoss erroneously expects connection-url tag to be present and just ignores it.

This issue has been called out in issues - **WFLY-6157** and **WFLY-6200**.

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand? I don't understand how this is an answer (my fault, I'm sure). I'm having this exact issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit late but the solution can be found in [redhat solutions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3975061). The issue is when defining non-XA datasource, datasource-class has been define in the datasource setup.

So what I did is goto admin console > configuration > subsystems > Datasource & drivers > Datasources > **< datasource name >** > click view.

on the attributes tab > click edit > delete the value in Datasource Class > save and reload server.

Test your connection now and it should be successful.

Comment: I could kiss you. But first Im going to wait in the red hat parking lot and beat up all their devs.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account Vaibhav1988's comments about "the datasource class needs explicit connection properties", in my case the solution was adding the following 2 properties under the datasource configuration:

databaseName=

ServerName=

In the Management Console go to "Subsystems" -> "Datasources & Drivers" -> "Datasources" then click on "View" in your datasource, go to "Connection" tab, click on "Edit" and add the properties in the field that says "Connection Properties".

Comment: This worked for me when attempting to connect to a DB2 running on an AS400.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me, edit file standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SqlServerdb" pool-name="SqlServerdb" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>
                    <connection-property name="databaseName">
                        DATABASENAME
                    </connection-property>
                    <connection-property name="ServerName">
                        IP(WITHOUT PORT)
                    </connection-property>
                    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>USER</user-name>
                        <password>PASSWORD</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    </validation>
</datasource>
```

and:

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```